# Elasticsearch 2.3.4 lost docs

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

I am using elasticsearch 2.3.4 to serve as a text search engine. And I have set a few indexes. But I found every couple days, the number of docs in my several indexes(politics,physics,biology) declined, which led to a decline in my search quality.

It should be:
[image]

It sometimes be:
[image]
Does anybody know what the possible reason is? Thanks for advance.

And below are the logs of that day:

```
[2018-03-21 14:22:58,349][WARN ][bootstrap                ] unable to install syscall filter: seccomp unavailable: CONFIG_SECCOMP not compiled into kernel, CONFIG_SECCOMP and CONFIG_SECCOMP_FILTER are needed
[2018-03-21 14:22:58,512][INFO ][node                     ] [es_knowledge_node2] version[2.3.4], pid[52771], build[e455fd0/2016-06-30T11:24:31Z]
[2018-03-21 14:22:58,512][INFO ][node                     ] [es_knowledge_node2] initializing ...
[2018-03-21 14:22:59,039][INFO ][plugins                  ] [es_knowledge_node2] modules [reindex, lang-expression, lang-groovy], plugins [elasticsearch-analysis-ansj, head, analysis-ik], sites [elasticsearch-analysis-ansj, head]
[2018-03-21 14:22:59,063][INFO ][env                      ] [es_knowledge_node2] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/sda2)]], net usable_space [43gb], net total_space [1.3tb], spins? [possibly], types [ext4]
[2018-03-21 14:22:59,063][INFO ][env                      ] [es_knowledge_node2] heap size [989.8mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2018-03-21 14:22:59,063][WARN ][env                      ] [es_knowledge_node2] max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process likely too low, consider increasing to at least [65536]
[2018-03-21 14:23:00,113][INFO ][ik-analyzer              ] try load config from /usr/local/elasticsearch-2.3.4/config/analysis-ik/IKAnalyzer.cfg.xml
[2018-03-21 14:23:00,113][INFO ][ik-analyzer              ] try load config from /usr/local/elasticsearch-2.3.4/plugins/ik/config/IKAnalyzer.cfg.xml
[2018-03-21 14:23:00,324][INFO ][ik-analyzer              ] [Dict Loading] custom/mydict.dic
[2018-03-21 14:23:00,324][INFO ][ik-analyzer              ] [Dict Loading] custom/single_word_low_freq.dic
[2018-03-21 14:23:00,327][INFO ][ik-analyzer              ] [Dict Loading] custom/ext_stopword.dic
[2018-03-21 14:23:00,341][WARN ][DICLOG                   ] not find library.properties. and err Can't find bundle for base name library, locale zh_CN i think it is a bug!
[2018-03-21 14:23:00,341][WARN ][DICLOG                   ] not find library.properties in classpath use it by default !
[2018-03-21 14:23:00,344][WARN ][DICLOG                   ] init userLibrary  warning :/usr/local/elasticsearch-2.3.4/config/ansj/dic/user because : file not found or failed to read !
[2018-03-21 14:23:00,345][WARN ][DICLOG                   ] init ambiguity  warning :/usr/local/elasticsearch-2.3.4/config/ansj/dic/ambiguity.dic because : file not found or failed to read !
[2018-03-21 14:23:00,855][INFO ][DICLOG                   ] init user userLibrary ok path is : /usr/local/elasticsearch-2.3.4/plugins/elasticsearch-analysis-ansj/default.dic
[2018-03-21 14:23:00,856][INFO ][ansj-initializer         ] Can't find the file:ansj/dic/stopLibrary.dic, no such file or directory exists!
[2018-03-21 14:23:01,302][INFO ][DICLOG                   ] init core library ok use time :436
[2018-03-21 14:23:01,754][INFO ][DICLOG                   ] init ngram ok use time :393
[2018-03-21 14:23:01,758][INFO ][ansj-initializer         ] ansj分词器预热完毕，可以使用!
[2018-03-21 14:23:01,758][INFO ][ansj-initializer         ] 没有找到redis相关配置!
[2018-03-21 14:23:01,759][INFO ][ansj-initializer         ] regedit analyzer named : index_ansj
[2018-03-21 14:23:01,760][INFO ][ansj-initializer         ] regedit analyzer named : query_ansj
[2018-03-21 14:23:01,760][INFO ][ansj-initializer         ] regedit analyzer named : to_ansj
[2018-03-21 14:23:01,760][INFO ][ansj-initializer         ] regedit analyzer named : dic_ansj
[2018-03-21 14:23:01,760][INFO ][ansj-initializer         ] regedit analyzer named : user_ansj
[2018-03-21 14:23:01,760][INFO ][ansj-initializer         ] regedit analyzer named : search_ansj
[2018-03-21 14:23:02,131][INFO ][node                     ] [es_knowledge_node2] initialized
[2018-03-21 14:23:02,132][INFO ][node                     ] [es_knowledge_node2] starting ...
[2018-03-21 14:23:02,226][INFO ][transport                ] [es_knowledge_node2] publish_address {10.1.1.11:9300}, bound_addresses {10.1.1.11:9300}
[2018-03-21 14:23:02,230][INFO ][discovery                ] [es_knowledge_node2] es_knowledge/3ipa2EdTRBOlW2oBrymwwA
[2018-03-21 14:23:22,330][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [es_knowledge_node2] detected_master {es_knowledge_node1}{g2eRdExvRKmSDvqpk_mkbA}{10.1.1.10}{10.1.1.10:9300}, added {{es_knowledge_node1}{g2eRdExvRKmSDvqpk_mkbA}{10.1.1.10}{10.1.1.10:9300},}, reason: zen-disco-receive(from master [{es_knowledge_node1}{g2eRdExvRKmSDvqpk_mkbA}{10.1.1.10}{10.1.1.10:9300}])
[2018-03-21 14:23:22,341][INFO ][cluster.routing.allocation.decider] [es_knowledge_node2] updating [cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.low] to [90%]
[2018-03-21 14:23:22,484][INFO ][http                     ] [es_knowledge_node2] publish_address {10.1.1.11:9200}, bound_addresses {10.1.1.11:9200}
[2018-03-21 14:23:22,485][INFO ][node                     ] [es_knowledge_node2] started
[2018-03-21 14:23:22,537][INFO ][ansj-initializer         ] regedit analyzer tokenizer named : index_ansj
[2018-03-21 14:23:22,537][INFO ][ansj-initializer         ] regedit analyzer tokenizer named : query_ansj
[2018-03-21 14:23:22,537][INFO ][ansj-initializer         ] regedit analyzer tokenizer named : to_ansj
[2018-03-21 14:23:22,537][INFO ][ansj-initializer         ] regedit analyzer tokenizer named : dic_ansj
[2018-03-21 14:23:22,538][INFO ][ansj-initializer         ] regedit analyzer tokenizer named : user_ansj
[2018-03-21 14:23:22,538][INFO ][ansj-initializer         ] regedit analyzer tokenizer named : search_ansj
[2018-03-21 14:23:22,546][INFO ][ansj-initializer         ] regedit analyzer provider named : index_ansj
[2018-03-21 14:23:22,547][INFO ][ansj-initializer         ] regedit analyzer provider named : query_ansj
[2018-03-21 14:23:22,547][INFO ][ansj-initializer         ] regedit analyzer provider named : to_ansj
[2018-03-21 14:23:22,547][INFO ][ansj-initializer         ] regedit analyzer provider named : dic_ansj
[2018-03-21 14:23:22,547][INFO ][ansj-initializer         ] regedit analyzer provider named : user_ansj
[2018-03-21 14:23:22,547][INFO ][ansj-initializer         ] regedit analyzer provider named : search_ansj
[2018-03-21 14:23:24,596][INFO ][ik-analyzer              ] try load config from /usr/local/elasticsearch-2.3.4/config/analysis-ik/IKAnalyzer.cfg.xml
[2018-03-21 14:23:24,596][INFO ][ik-analyzer              ] try load config from /usr/local/elasticsearch-2.3.4/plugins/ik/config/IKAnalyzer.cfg.xml
[2018-03-21 14:23:24,599][INFO ][ik-analyzer              ] try load config from /usr/local/elasticsearch-2.3.4/config/analysis-ik/IKAnalyzer.cfg.xml
[2018-03-21 14:23:24,600][INFO ][ik-analyzer              ] try load config from /usr/local/elasticsearch-2.3.4/plugins/ik/config/IKAnalyzer.cfg.xml
[2018-03-21 14:23:24,602][INFO ][ik-analyzer              ] try load config from /usr/local/elasticsearch-2.3.4/config/analysis-ik/IKAnalyzer.cfg.xml
[2018-03-21 14:23:24,602][INFO ][ik-analyzer              ] try load config from /usr/local/elasticsearch-2.3.4/plugins/ik/config/IKAnalyzer.cfg.xml
[2018-03-21 17:13:16,200][WARN ][monitor.jvm              ] [es_knowledge_node2] [gc][young][10206][23] duration [6.5s], collections [1]/[7.2s], total [6.5s]/[7s], memory [322.8mb]->[255.5mb]/[989.8mb], all_pools {[young] [68.2mb]->[573.8kb]/[273mb]}{[survivor] [8.4mb]->[2.1mb]/[34.1mb]}{[old] [246mb]->[252.8mb]/[682.6mb]}
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific about your question. Decline in the sense how. On day 1 what is the count and day 2 what is the count. ?

Comment: @Vijayakumar I am sorry I did not shoot the screen and have updated the index already. Next time it occurs, I will upload the picture.

Comment: @Vijayakumar the count change has been added

Answer (score 0):

I can see some of the shards is not allocated properly. There are so many reasons for this and i will mention some of them

1. Low disk watermark
2. Too many shards, not enough nodes
3. You need to re-enable shard allocation

To pinpoint the exact problem

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cat/shards?h=index,shard,prirep,state,unassigned.reason| grep UNASSIGNED
```

Comment: Thank you. Now all of the shards is  allocated properly, but still the losing-docs error occurs. Alas!

Comment: Do you run any script to sync the data. Can you share the log file.